# Output the text of a cell that is NOT within a text list - IS IT POSSIBLE?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel I would like to output the text string in a cell that is not present in a text list.

For example:
I have cell A1 which contains AA,BB,CC

Now I have a list in Array B1:B5 containing

```
AA
BB
DD
EE
FF
```

What would the formula be so that CC is the output - a formula finding the text that is NOT in the list.

I have the formula to output those texts that are in the list which is:
TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(COUNTIF(A!, "*"&B1:B5&"*"), B1:B5, ""))

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: How about `SUBSTITUTE` formula after the first formula. Say the `TEXTJOIN(...` is in C1. Then `SUBSTITUTE(A1,C1,"")`. That will leave you with `,CC`. You can remove the comma as well with `LEFT`,`MID`, another `SUBSTITUTE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UDF to do this if you are open to VBA solution...

---

```
Public Function ABSENT(Target As Range) As String

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long, Found As Range, Temp
Temp = Split(Target, ",")

For i = LBound(Temp) To UBound(Temp)
    Set Found = ws.Range("B2:B6").Find(Trim(Temp(i)))
        If Found Is Nothing Then
            ABSENT = ABSENT & Trim(Temp(i)) & ", "
        End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

If Len(ABSENT) Then
    ABSENT = Left(ABSENT, Len(ABSENT) - 2)
Else
    ABSENT = ""
End If

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Excel 365**, in **C1** enter:

```
=LET(fx,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),z,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(fx,B1:B5,0)),fx,""),FILTER(z,z<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2019, you can try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<x><t>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1&",",",","<s>,"&TEXTJOIN(",",,B1:B5)&",</s></t><t>")&"</t></x>","//t[.//*[not(contains(.,concat(',',../text(),',')))]]"))
```

[image]

This would need `CSE` entering. However, a nice Excel365 alternative is allready provided by @GarysStudent.